# can't customize tomcat7 404 error page

Tags: linux, tomcat7

I am trying to customize tomcat7 error page. I need global settings for all the context paths, so I've end up with the configuration inside global **/etc/tomcat/web.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
<error-page>
       <error-code>404</error-code>
       <location>/custom-pages/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Tomcat succeeds in returning the page when I ask it:

```
curl -s 127.0.0.1:8080/custom-pages/error.jsp

<html><body>Sorry, the page you requested were not found.</html></body>
```

However when I request some page which does not exist I get a default error page comes with tomcat, but not the my one:

```
curl 127.0.0.1:8080/not-exist
<html><head><title>Error report</title></head>
<body><h1>HTTP Status 404 - /not-exist</h1></body>
</html>
```

Here is the layout of tomcat web directories:

```
tree /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/
/usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/
└── ROOT
    └── custom-pages
        └── error.jsp
```

And the content of custom error page:

```
cat /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/custom-pages/error.jsp
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<html><body>Sorry, the page you requested were not found.</body></html>
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your closing tags are switched in the order they're expected. Could be a typo and not sure that'd affect anything,  but worth noting. `</html></body>` shoudl be `</body></html>`

Comment: Hi! Yes it is a typo. Anyway thanks for noticing this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, meanwhile I have found the answer. I had to comment **org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve** directive inside **/etc/tomcat7/context.xml** and it did the trick. Looks like this directive "overrides" any custom error pages! Hopefully will be useful for others ... :

```
<!-- 
 <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve"
 showReport="false" showServerInfo="false" /> 
-->
```